# Problema con Archivos (Ordenar sus datos) (Java)

Tags: java, archivo

Muy buenas con todos.

He estado resolviendo un problema con un grupo de trabajo en el que trata sobre crear tres archivos diferentes (.txt). El proceso va así:

1. El programa pide la cantidad de datos que el archivo va a contener
2. Se llenan los datos (números enteros) uno por uno
3. Se repite el proceso hasta crear tres archivos diferentes. Todos con formato .txt
4. Los datos ingresados en los archivos anteriores deben ser transportados a un 4to archivo (también .txt)
5. El archivo debe tener los datos ordenados de menor a mayor o al revés según se desee

Sin embargo, no lo hago compilar del todo. Necesito su ayuda por favor. Adjunto el código avanzado hasta ahora:

```
//Une los archivos en uno solo
package Archivos;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArchivoResult {


    File Aresult = new File("Aresult.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void CrearAresult() {

        if (!Aresult.exists()) {
            try {
                Aresult.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(Aresult.getName() + " Tu archivoa sido creado");

            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void CopiarArchivos() {
        FileInputStream origen1 = null;
        FileInputStream origen2 = null;
        FileInputStream origen3 = null;


        FileOutputStream destino = null;
        File f1 = new File("A1.txt");
        File f2 = new File("A2.txt");
        File f3 = new File("A3.txt");
        File fr = new File("Aresult.txt");

        try {
            origen1 = new FileInputStream(f1);
            origen2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
            origen3 = new FileInputStream(f3);
            destino = new FileOutputStream(fr);

            int a,b,c;
            while ((c = origen1.read()) != -1) {
                destino.write(c);    
            }
            while ((a = origen2.read()) != -1) {
                destino.write(a);    
            }
            while ((b = origen3.read()) != -1) {
                destino.write(b);    
            }

                origen1.close();
                origen2.close();
                origen3.close();
                destino.close();
        } catch (IOException er) {
            System.out.println(er.getMessage());
        } 

    }

    public void MostrarDatos() {
        try {
            System.out.println("tus datos ingresados son: ");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(Aresult);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String datos;
            while ((datos = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(" " + datos);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

     public String Cadena(){
        String result="";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(Aresult);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             String temp="";
             String bfread;
            while ((bfread = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp=bfread+",";
            }
            result=temp;
            br.close();
            fr.close();     
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int[] Ordenamiento(String [] b){
        String cadena=Cadena();
        b=cadena.split(",");
        int tmp[]=new int[b.length];

        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
            tmp[i]= Integer.parseInt(b[i]); //Aquí está el error
        }
        int aux;

        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length-1;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.length-1;i++){
                if(tmp[i]>tmp[i+1]){
                    aux=tmp[i];
                    tmp[i]=tmp[i+1];
                    tmp[i+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }    
        return tmp;
    }

    public void Sobreescribir(int[] c){
        Borrar();
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Aresult);
            PrintWriter linea=new PrintWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                linea.print(c[i]+",");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void Borrar(){
        this.Aresult.delete();
        try{
            this.Aresult.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

ARCHIVO 1

```
package Archivos;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Archivos1 {

    File A1 = new File("A1.txt");
    private int num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void CrearA1() {

        if (!A1.exists()) {
            try {
                A1.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(A1.getName() + " Ha sido creado");

            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int IngresarDatos() {
//        num=dato;
        int n=-1;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A1);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingresa tus datos");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int dato = sc.nextInt();
                bw.write(dato + ",");
            }

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito");
        return n;
    }

    public void MostrarDatos() {
        try {
            System.out.println("tus datos ingresados son: ");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String datos;
            while ((datos = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(" " + datos);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String Cadena(){
        String result="";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             String temp="";
             String bfread;
            while ((bfread = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp=bfread+",";
            }
            result=temp;
            br.close();
            fr.close();     
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int[] Ordenamiento(String [] b){
        String cadena=Cadena();
        b=cadena.split(",");
        int tmp[]=new int[b.length];

        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
            tmp[i]= Integer.parseInt(b[i]);
        }
        int aux;

        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length-1;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.length-1;i++){
                if(tmp[i]>tmp[i+1]){
                    aux=tmp[i];
                    tmp[i]=tmp[i+1];
                    tmp[i+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public void Sobreescribir(int[] c){
        Borrar();
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A1);
            PrintWriter linea=new PrintWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                linea.print(c[i]+",");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void Borrar(){
        this.A1.delete();
        try{
            this.A1.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

ARCHIVO 2

```
package Archivos;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Archivo2 {

    File A2 = new File("A2.txt");
    private int num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void CrearA2() {

        if (!A2.exists()) {
            try {
                A2.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(A2.getName() + " Ha sido creado");

            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int IngresarDatos() {
        int n=-1;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A2);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea");
             n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingresa tus datos");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int dato = sc.nextInt();
                bw.write(dato + ",");
            }

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito");
        return n;
    }

    public void MostrarDatos() {
        try {
            System.out.println("tus datos ingresados son: ");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A2);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String datos;
            while ((datos = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(" " + datos);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String Cadena(){
        String result="";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A2);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             String temp="";
             String bfread;
            while ((bfread = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp=bfread+",";
            }
            result=temp;
            br.close();
            fr.close();     
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int[] Ordenamiento(String [] b){
        String cadena=Cadena();
        b=cadena.split(",");
        int tmp[]=new int[b.length];

        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
            tmp[i]= Integer.parseInt(b[i]);
        }
        int aux;

        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length-1;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.length-1;i++){
                if(tmp[i]>tmp[i+1]){
                    aux=tmp[i];
                    tmp[i]=tmp[i+1];
                    tmp[i+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }    
        return tmp;
    }

    public void Sobreescribir(int[] c){
        Borrar();
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A2);
            PrintWriter linea=new PrintWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                linea.print(c[i]+",");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void Borrar(){
        this.A2.delete();
        try{
            this.A2.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

ARCHIVO 3

```
package Archivos;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Archivo3 {

    File A3 = new File("A3.txt");
    private int num;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void CrearA3() {

        if (!A3.exists()) {
            try {
                A3.createNewFile();
                System.out.println(A3.getName() + " Ha sido creado");

            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int IngresarDatos() {
        int n=-1;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A3);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingresa tus datos");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int dato = sc.nextInt();
                bw.write(dato + ",");
            }

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito");
        return n;
    }

    public void MostrarDatos() {
        try {
            System.out.println("tus datos ingresados son: ");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A3);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String datos;
            while ((datos = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(" " + datos);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String Cadena(){
        String result="";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(A3);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
             String temp="";
             String bfread;
            while ((bfread = br.readLine()) != null) {
                temp=bfread+",";
            }
            result=temp;
            br.close();
            fr.close();     
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int[] Ordenamiento(String [] b){
        String cadena=Cadena();
        b=cadena.split(",");
        int tmp[]=new int[b.length];

        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){
            tmp[i]= Integer.parseInt(b[i]);
        }
        int aux;

        for(int j=0;j<tmp.length-1;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.length-1;i++){
                if(tmp[i]>tmp[i+1]){
                    aux=tmp[i];
                    tmp[i]=tmp[i+1];
                    tmp[i+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }    
        return tmp;
    }

    public void Sobreescribir(int[] c){
        Borrar();
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(A3);
            PrintWriter linea=new PrintWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                linea.print(c[i]+",");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void Borrar(){
        this.A3.delete();
        try{
            this.A3.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Si pudieran ayudarme estaría muy agradecido. Muchas gracias

Ps: Olvidé poner la clase main

```
//Clase Main
   package Archivos;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Archivos1 A1 = new Archivos1();
        Archivo2 A2 = new Archivo2();
        Archivo3 A3 =new Archivo3();
        ArchivoResult AR = new ArchivoResult();


        A1.CrearA1();
        System.out.println("ARCHIVO 1");
        System.out.println("=========");
        int cont=A1.IngresarDatos();
        String tmp[]=new String[cont];
        int ar1[]=A1.Ordenamiento(tmp);
        A1.Sobreescribir(ar1);
        A1.MostrarDatos();


        A2.CrearA2();
        System.out.println("ARCHIVO 2");
        System.out.println("=========");
        int cont2=A2.IngresarDatos();
        String tmp2[]=new String[cont2];
        int ar2[]=A2.Ordenamiento(tmp2);
        A2.Sobreescribir(ar2);
        A2.MostrarDatos();


        A3.CrearA3();
        System.out.println("ARCHIVO 3");
        System.out.println("=========");
        int cont3=A3.IngresarDatos();
        String tmp3[]=new String[cont3];
        int ar3[]=A3.Ordenamiento(tmp3);
        A3.Sobreescribir(ar3);
        A3.MostrarDatos();


        int cont4=cont+cont2+cont3;
        AR.CrearAresult();
        System.out.println("ARCHIVO RESULTANTE");
        System.out.println("==================");
        AR.CopiarArchivos();
        String tmp4[]=new String[cont4];
        int ar4[]=AR.Ordenamiento(tmp4);
        AR.Sobreescribir(ar4);
        AR.MostrarDatos();


    }

}
```

Comment: No se entiende qué tiene que tener cada uno de los 4 archivos ni de donde vienen los datos. ¿Se leen por teclado? Por favor aclara un poco lo que necesitas hacer, y añade algún ejemplo de lo que tendrían que tener esos ficheros en función de la entrada.

Comment: Lamento eso. Olvidé ponerle la clase Main. Disculpa por ello. Además también anexaré una corrida del algoritmo:

Comment: ARCHIVO 1
=========
Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea
3 //teclado
Ingresa tus datos
1 //teclado
0 //teclado
5 //teclado
tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito
tus datos ingresados son: 
ARCHIVO 2
=========
Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea
2 //teclado
Ingresa tus datos
0 //teclado
6 //teclado
tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito
tus datos ingresados son: 
ARCHIVO 3
=========
Ingrese la cantidad de datos que desea
2 //teclado
Ingresa tus datos
0 //teclado
5 //teclado
tus numeros han sido añadidos con éxito

Comment: tus datos ingresados son: 
ARCHIVO RESULTANTE
==================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Archivos.ArchivoResult.Ordenamiento(ArchivoResult.java:105)
 at Archivos.Main.main(Main.java:52)
C:\Users\edu_i\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)